# Equal margins between row elements

Tags: css, row, element

I am trying to make equal margins between row elements. I put the text into wells and I want these wells to have equal margins, i.e. the first and the second row should have the same space between its blocks. But unfortunately, the second row elements do not conform to the set parameters.

```
  div.well{
height:600px;
display:inline-block
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
overflow: auto;
   }
```

I have a question that really bothers me! Why is that so? Why do the elements of the first row correspond to the parameters but the second don't?

http://codepen.io/Zarina-374/pen/KMVevP

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Apply `text-align: center` or `text-align: left` on `.jumbotron`

Answer (score 0):

There is a semi-colon missing after `display:inline-block` in -

```
div.well{
height:600px;
display:inline-block
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Also add this css

```
.jumbotron{
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: OMG! That simple? Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 0):

plz add a semi column to "display:inline-block;"
its working

```
 div.well{
    height:600px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow: auto;
       }
```

Comment: thank you! double-check! I should never forget about it!